# MySql select single instance of a 3 field combo based on lowest value of 4th field

Tags: mysql, select

I'm wondering if anyone can help with this more complicated select query. I have included a subset of the data and the logic of the select statement below. I am having real trouble starting on this one:

```
department  position    grade   salary  
sales       manager     A       40,000
sales       manager     A       35,000
hr          manager     A       27,000
hr          assistant   B       17,000
hr          assistant   B       17,000
IT          manager     A       45,000
IT          manager     C       40,000
IT          assistant   B       27,000
```

For every unique POSITION + GRADE (ie. manager + A, manager + B, manager + C, assistant + A, assistant + B, assistant + C) I want to return a max of 1 entry per department

In the event of a department having more than 1 entry for the same  POSITION + GRADE, then the entry with the lowest salary be returned.

The only entry I can be sure will be static is that GRADE will always be A,B or C. Any other field could change.

Query should return :

```
department  position    grade   salary  
sales       manager     A       35,000
hr          manager     A       27,000
hr          assistant   B       17,000
IT          manager     A       45,000
IT          manager     C       40,000
IT          assistant   B       27,000
```

Can I build some sort of DISTINCT query based on department+position+grade and return lowest value salary?

Comment: Does it have to be done in a query? It so, it looks like a good candidate for using MAX, MIN, and GROUP BY.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple `LEFT JOIN` can check for people with the same department/position/grade and find the one with the lowest salary. The `DISTINCT` is added to avoid duplicates with the same salary;

```
SELECT DISTINCT t1.*
FROM Table1 t1
LEFT JOIN Table1 t2
  ON t1.position = t2.position
 AND t1.grade = t2.grade
 AND t1.department = t2.department
 AND t1.salary > t2.salary
WHERE t2.salary IS NULL;
```

[An SQLfiddle to test with](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/fb984/3).

Comment: Excellent! Works as required - thanks for the SQLfiddle as well. Much appreciated.